# Read Serial Port on C# allocating on an array no forgetting "00"

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, serial-port

I'm trying to do a program that reads a serie of data from a serial port (COM3). The problem is that my code is for example (in decimal):

> 170 85 01 128 01 129 46 00 00 00 00 00 05 46

The way I'm reading the bytes "00" aren't been allocated on the array or variable:
I try a lot of ways like:

```
await port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);
```

And like shows on microsoft web site:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

class PortDataReceived
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);
    }
}
```

But all this methods doesn't work.
Does any one knows any way from get this data and allocate in an array?

Comment: ReadExisting() is only suitable when the device sends strings.  It does not send a string, it sends binary data.  Use the Read() method instead.  Do not ignore its return value.

Comment: @HansPassant I change the end but occurs the same thing:

`private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            byte[] indata = new byte[55];
            sp.Read(indata, 0, 55);
            Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");

            for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(indata[i]);
            }
}`

Comment: *Do not ignore its return value*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something to investigate what's happening?  If you start a new Winforms project with a single form, a button (buttonStart), and six text boxes, and then put this code behind it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int RxRead;
    int n;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.Open();

    }


    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (n = 0; n < 23; n++)
        {

            if (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                RxRead = serialPort1.ReadByte();
                if (n == 0)
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText(RxRead.ToString());
                }
                if (n == 1)
                {
                    textBox2.AppendText(RxRead.ToString());
                }
                if (n == 2)
                {
                    textBox3.AppendText(RxRead.ToString());
                }
                if (n == 3)
                {
                    textBox4.AppendText(RxRead.ToString());
                }
                if (n == 4)
                {
                    textBox5.AppendText(RxRead.ToString());
                }
                if (n == 5)
                {
                    textBox6.AppendText(RxRead.ToString());
                }
                if (n == 6)
                {
                    serialPort1.Close();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then I would hope that, when you press the start button, you will get the first six bytes displayed in the text boxes.  This would let you see whether the 00 bytes are actually being read at all, or whether they are being discarded for some reason?  I haven't got a serial port hooked up on my machine, so my apologies if there are any errors in the code.

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: I'm felling embarrassed, since the beginning my code was right `(await port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 50);)` the problem was the Arduino that was sending the wrongs bytes. Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem at all.  Great that you got it working!  Best of luck

Answer (score -1):

If it's any help, here is a program that I wrote a long while back to pick up data coming in over a serial port from two sensors. It's very clunky programming, but as I recall it did (mostly!) work, so there may be something you can use.

Cheers,
Nick

[[image]][1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace serial_port_with_events_attempt_4
{ 
public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    string RxString;
    int RxRead;
    int i;
    int j;
    int RxDec1;
    int RxDec2;
    int RxDec3;
    float RxFloat;
    float RxFloat2;
    string locnString = "Unknown";
    DateTime deleteDate;
    string deleteDateString;
    string testString;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        deleteDate = DateTime.Today;
        deleteDate = deleteDate.AddDays(-7);
        deleteDateString = deleteDate.ToString();
        textBox1.AppendText(deleteDateString);
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM8";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;

        serialPort1.Open();
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            buttonStart.Enabled = false;
            buttonStop.Enabled = true;
              //textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
        }
    }

    private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            buttonStart.Enabled = true;
            buttonStop.Enabled = false;
            //textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<23 ; j++)
        {

                if (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    RxRead = serialPort1.ReadByte();
                    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
                }

        }



    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if (RxRead == 126)
        {
            //textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            i = 0;
        }

        if (i< 23)
        {
            if (i == 13)
            {
                testString = RxRead.ToString();
                textBox1.AppendText(testString);
                if (RxRead == 82) // 82 in this position means that the temp sensor is the low range one (R1L)
                { 
                   //textBox1.AppendText("Temperature in Nick's office = ");
                   locnString = ("Nicks office");
                }

                if (RxRead == 195) // 195 in this position means that the temp sensor is the high range one (R1H)
                {
                    //textBox1.AppendText("Temperature in Nick's office = ");
                    locnString = ("Sitting Room");
                }
            }

            if (i == 17)
            {
                RxDec1 = RxRead - 48; // Read the tens unit
            }

            if (i == 18)
            {
                RxDec2 = RxRead - 48; // Read the units
            }

            if (i == 20)
            {
                RxDec3 = RxRead - 49; // read the decimal
            }

            if (i == 22)
            {
                RxFloat = ((RxDec1 * 10) + RxDec2);
                RxFloat2 = RxDec3;
                RxFloat2 = RxFloat2 / 10;
                RxFloat = RxFloat + RxFloat2;
                // Frig about to get the reads in the right format and added together


                RxString = RxFloat.ToString();
                if (RxFloat < 30 && RxFloat >10)
                {

                //textBox1.AppendText(RxString);
                    if (locnString == "Nicks office")
                    {
                      button1.Text = RxString;
                    }
                    if (locnString == "Sitting Room")
                    {
                        button2.Text = RxString;
                    }

                // Put the value in the main text box if it is not corrupt, (checking if the range is reasonable
                temperature1DataSetTableAdapters.Temp1TableAdapter temp1tableadapter = new temperature1DataSetTableAdapters.Temp1TableAdapter();
                temp1tableadapter.Insert(DateTime.Now, RxFloat, locnString);
                // Add a new line into the temperature database
                }

                deleteDate = DateTime.Today;
                deleteDate = deleteDate.AddDays(-7);
                deleteDateString = deleteDate.ToString();
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.AppendText(deleteDateString);
                temperature1DataSetTableAdapters.TempTableAdapter temp2tableadapter = new temperature1DataSetTableAdapters.TempTableAdapter();
                temp2tableadapter.DeleteTempQuery(deleteDate);
                //textBox1.AppendText("BreakpointA");
                textBox1.AppendText(testString);
                // Delete any old data.
                 // TODO Doesn't seem to be working.  Don't understand why not.  The code gets to here as Breakpoint A gets triggered

                this.tempTableAdapter.Fill(this.temperature1DataSet.Temp);
                chart1.DataBind();
                // These two lines refresh the chart.  Took me a long time to figure this out.  Basically, you have to 
                // rerun the query and then run the DataBind method to update the chart control.
                // Good article on table adapters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28VS.80%29.aspx

                //** test code for second chart.
                this.tempSensor2AdapterTableAdapter.tempSensor2Fill(this.temperature1DataSet.tempSensor2Adapter);
                chart2.DataBind();

            }
         }
            i=i+1;
     }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'temperature1DataSet.tempSensor2Adapter' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tempSensor2AdapterTableAdapter.tempSensor2Fill(this.temperature1DataSet.tempSensor2Adapter);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'temperature1DataSet.Temp' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tempTableAdapter.Fill(this.temperature1DataSet.Temp);
        chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:dd/MM H:mm}";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:dd/MM H:mm}";

    }


    }
}
```

Comment: I see this got downvoted.  So that I can avoid it in the future, could anyone comment on what's wrong?

Comment: Thanks so much @Nick879 but even with your software occurs the same thing, the bytes 00 aren't shown on screen. By the way, I don't why it was downvoted.